# How to map over a table without a foreign key

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

```
   TABLE BOOKING (
  BOOK_ID  
  PERSONAL_ID                             
  ORGINIZER                      
  TITLE
    PRIMARY KEY ( BOOK_ID )
    FOREIGN KEY ( PERSONAL_ID)
);

TABLE PERSONAL
    (
      ID
      NAME
      SURNAME
      EMAIL         
      PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
    );
```

My Question is how can i map over the Table PERSONAL? My Problem is that PERSONAL doesn't have a FOREIGN KEY so i don't know how to map over PERSONAL. I need to get the NAME, SURNAME and EMAIL from that table.

Hope someone can help.

my mapping looks like this so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

  <class name="Depp.Domain.Booking, Depp.Core" >
    <id name="ID" unsaved-value="0" column="ID">
      <generator class="native">
        <!--<param name="sequence">GLOBALSEQUENCE</param>-->
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Title" ></property>
    <property name="TitleEnabled" type="yes_no">
      <column name="THEMA_ENABLED"/>
    </property>
    <property name="ORGANIZER" column="PERSONAL_ID" not-null="true" ></property>

    <many-to-one name="Personal" class="Book.Domain.Booking, Book.Core" column="Personal_ID"
            not-null="true" />

  </class>


  <class name="Book.Domain.Personal, Book.Core">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <component name="Booker" class="Book.Domain.Person, Book.Core">
      <property name="Name" column="NN" />
      <property name="Surname" column="VN"/>
      <property name="Email" column="EMAIL" />
      <property name="Phone" column="TEL" />
    </component>
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

if i use the many to one relationship the website crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You write:

> the website crashes

That's not quite a detailed bug report ;-). It helps us help you if you provide more detail.

In any case, from the mapping I can see one thing that's probably wrong: in the `<many-to-one />` you need to indicate the class of the property you're mapping ("Personal"), not the containing class ("Booking"). Try something along these lines:

```
<many-to-one name="Personal" 
    class="Book.Domain.Personal, Book.Core" 
    column="Personal_ID"
    not-null="true" />
```

The main difference is in the `class` attribute. I think you may even be able to omit the attribute altogether, and let NHibernate infer it from the entity's property type.

For more info see the [many-to-one](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) documentation.